# Does 文 refer only to written sentences, or can it be used for spoken sentences as well?

Tags: words

I know that this kanji is associated with writing and text, and can mean "sentence."  When using it to mean "sentence", is it only a written sentence? I can't find any examples that unambiguously demonstrate that it can be a spoken sentence as well.

Comment: Just being curious, what kind of examples do you think unambiguously demonstrate English "sentence" stands for a spoken sentence as well?

Comment: "She always raises her voice at the end of a sentence, like she's asking a question."  
Pretty much any sentence that mentions someone saying a sentence, rather than writing/reading one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

文 refers to a sentence, regardless of whether it's written or spoken. I find no significant discrepancy in usage between Japanese '文' and English 'sentence' here.

For example you can say something like 命令文のイントネーション (intonation of an imperative sentence), which unequivocally refers to a spoken sentence.